# How to get the row count of a TreeTableView?

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

***Edit***: I now accept that the method `TreeTableView.getExpandedItemCount()` in fact appears to count all the `TreeItem`s currently displayed. This makes this method one of the most egregiously badly named methods I have ever had the misfortune to come across, for incontrovertible reasons stated in my original question, and reiterated in several comments.

---

A simple tree iterator can be devised to count all the items (regardless of whether showing, or concealed due to one or more ancestors being collapsed) in a `TreeTableView`'s column0 (the tree column).

But I can't find a way of counting the rows which are "displayed". I say "displayed" rather than "visible" because a tree row can be displayed without necessarily being visible.

I note that there is a method `TreeTableView.getExpandedItemCount()`. This doesn't tell you quite what I want to know: you can have a set of leaves, each taking up one row, none of which is expanded. Equally it's possible that these expanded items might include `TreeItem`s one or more of whose ancestors is in fact collapsed: just because a `TreeItem` is expanded doesn't mean it is displayed.

I also had a look at `TreeTableColumn`. I couldn't see anything very obvious there.

The only solution I can think of is supremely inelegant:

```
// NB TreeIterator is a simple depth-first stack-based iterator
TreeIterator iterator = new TreeIterator(treeTableView.getRoot());
int nRows = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    TreeItem ti = iterator.next();
    int row = treeTableView.getRow( ti );
    if( row > nRows ) nRows = row;
}
log.debug( "displayed rows " + nRows );
```

... there MUST, surely, be something better than that.

Comment: How about  `getroot().getChildren().size()`

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: @c0der Please go and look up trees.

Comment: @M.S. Why do you ask? 11.0.2.

Comment: @mikerodent I'm asking because I'm trying to help

Comment: mike rodent As @c0der said, please check the value of getRoot().getChildren().size(). A TreeTableView is a subclass of other JavaFX objects, and some methods are inherited.

Comment: @NomadMaker you also need to go and look up trees

Comment: @NomadMaker you definitely need to go and look up trees.

Comment: Compare your proposed solution to  `treeTableView.getRoot().getChildren().size()`

Comment: Why would I need to look up trees, and which specific object are you ordering us to look up? I've been developing in Java since the first public beta. While I don't know everything, I do know how to look them up.

Comment: `VirtualFlow` provides `getFirstVisibleCell()`, `getLastVisibleCell()`, `getLastVisibleCellWithinViewPort()` and `getFirstVisibleCellWithinViewPort()` methods.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @M.S. Please could you post an answer? How are we to get hold of such a `VirtualFlow` from the `TreeTableView`?

Comment: I am not a down voter but I must say I find you responses unpleasant.

Comment: a leaf cannot be expanded (or always is) - and expandedItemCount seems what you want ... except you didn't explain it well enough or I'm too tired to understand it <g>

Comment: expandedItemCount _is essentially the count of all expanded tree items, and their children._ don't understand how that can possibly be misunderstood ..

Comment: @kleopatra I now accept that that is what that method (astonishingly) delivers.  But this makes it a shockingly badly named method. The name should be `getDisplayedItems()`. I repeat (you of all people with your compendious knowledge of all things Java GUI must know this): if you expand `TreeItem` X and then collapse one of its ancestors, in event Y, `TreeItem` X remains expanded, although it and all the TreeItems displayed under it prior to collapse event Y are now **non-displayed**.  Expansion involves display but an "expanded items" count is VERY different to a "displayed items" count.

Comment: Names are often open to debate, but don't matter at the end of the day: _do_ read the spec of, _do not_ assume anything about a method ;) From the perspective of the tree, an expanded subtree under a collapsed node is irrelevant .. so both naming and implementation look okay for me. Anyway, this particular discussion leads nowhere, *off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `TreeTableView.getExpandedItemCount()` gives the number of rows displayed. Before it was realized that this simple solution was on offer, alternative solutions for getting the same thing were found as follows:

```java
private static int getVisibleCellCount(TreeTableView<?> treeTableView) {
    TreeTableViewSkin<?> skin = (TreeTableViewSkin<?>) treeTableView.getSkin();
    Optional<VirtualFlow> vf = skin.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(child -> child instanceof VirtualFlow)
            .map(VirtualFlow.class::cast)
            .findFirst();
    if (vf.isPresent()) {
        VirtualFlow<?> virtualFlow = vf.get();
        IndexedCell first = virtualFlow.getFirstVisibleCell();
        if (first != null) {
            return virtualFlow.getCellCount();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: Again, this is not a solution to the real problem. The solution only shows how to get the first cell and last cell in the viewport.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211065/discussion-on-answer-by-m-s-how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-treetableview).